# Clarification on regular expression matching for logical AND and OR with Boost

Tags: c++, regex, windows, boost

I need to match two types of strings using regular expressions:

```
//Look for "keyboard" AND "mouse"
(?=.*keyboard)(?=.*mouse)
```

and

```
//Look for "keyboard" OR "mouse"
(keyboard)|(mouse)
```

I run this code using the Boost library:

```
static const boost::regex e("(?=.*keyboard)(?=.*mouse)");
string chat_input("keyboard & mouse");
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> results;
if (boost::regex_match(chat_input, results, e))
{
    //Got a match
}
```

Both regexps return `no match`. Am I using the wrong syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

boost::regex_match is a full match by default, so you can use this regex `".*(keyboard|mouse).*"` to match the string. Or you can pass one more parameter to let it to do a partial match.

```
boost::regex_match(chat_input, results, e, boost::match_default | boost::match_partial)
```

see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html

"The algorithm regex_match determines whether a given regular expression matches **all** of a given character sequence denoted by a pair of bidirectional-iterators, the algorithm is defined as follows, the main use of this function is data input validation."

and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/partial_matches.html

Comment: I should've used `boost::regex_search` instead and it will work.